# How to get that point (user location ) exist in circle zone in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

1. I have list of circle zone (Not Polygon !important)
2. i want to know that user exist on which circle zone (area) on basis of his location. (In MongoDB).

May you please provide me a good solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$geoWithin` function and programmatically construct the list of circles that will be supplied to the `find()` function.

```
circles = [];
//            lat,lon   radius
circles[0] = [ [0,0] , 2 ];
circles[1] = [ [4,0] , 4 ];
circles[2] = [ [8,8] , 2 ];

locs = [];
for(n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
  var pt = circles[n][0];
  var radius = circles[n][1];
  locs.push({"location": { $geoWithin :
            { $center : [ pt, radius ]
                    } }});
}

var q = {"$or": locs};

var c = db.geo.find(q);
   c.forEach(function(r) {
      printjson(r);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Buzz for your response.

Comment: Thanks @Buzz for your response. But location (geo) is not stored in collection. Like Current user location is 28.567,77.7678 and circle is stored in Collection. Now i want to get the circle which contain that lat and long. Your response is reverse of my question. Is it any other way to handle  it ?

Comment: Apols but I am not clearly grasping the question.   You know where the users are, e.g. one of them is at [28.567,77.7678].   That info is stored in some collection A.    Collection B contains the circle defs.   So pull the circle defs from collection B, then turn around and apply the query to collection A.   Is this close?

Comment: Yes.. @Buzz... Thanks